# Issue in angular component with animate.css

Tags: css, angular, animation, css-animations, angular-components

I am new to angular. This is third time i am asking same  question on stackoverflow but not any single answer that can solve my problem

I am converting a template in  angular component . Copied the source code from template and pasted the code in Index.html of Src folder in angular project and for the images,js,fonts pasted in assets folder . Every thing works fine .But when i moved content section from **Index.html** to **AppComponent.hml** **Animation used in this template stopped working** . I Have been trying this for more than 10 days .No idea where i am doing wrong . i have installed animate.css But **No Luck**

**Template URl :-** https://colorlib.com/wp/template/skillhunt/

**what I want to do** : I want to convert seperate content component section from this template

**Index.html **

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SkillIndia</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/animate.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/aos.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ionicons.min.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/jquery.timepicker.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/flaticon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/icomoon.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>
  <app-root>

  </app-root>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ftco_navbar bg-dark ftco-navbar-light" id="ftco-navbar">
    <div class="container-fluid px-md-4 ">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Skillhunt</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ftco-nav" aria-controls="ftco-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="oi oi-menu"></span> Menu
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ftco-nav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="browsejobs.html" class="nav-link">Browse Jobs</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="candidates.html" class="nav-link">Canditates</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="blog.html" class="nav-link">Blog</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item cta mr-md-1"><a href="new-post.html" class="nav-link">Post a Job</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item cta cta-colored"><a href="job-post.html" class="nav-link">Want a Job</a></li>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- END nav -->
  <div class="hero-wrap hero-wrap-2" style="background-image: url('assets/images/bg_1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row no-gutters slider-text align-items-end justify-content-start">
        <div class="col-md-12 ftco-animate text-center mb-5">
          <p class="breadcrumbs mb-0"><span class="mr-3"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></a></span> <span>Job Post</span></p>
          <h1 class="mb-3 bread">Post A Job</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/aos.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.animateNumber.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/scrollax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBVWaKrjvy3MaE7SQ74_uJiULgl1JY0H2s&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="assets/js/google-map.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

When the content section is Index then animation works fine .but when i move content to appcomponent animation does not work

**AppCompnent.html**

```
<router-outlet>


</router-outlet>
<div class="hero-wrap hero-wrap-2" style="background-image: url('assets/images/bg_1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters slider-text align-items-end justify-content-start">
      <div class="col-md-12 ftco-animate text-center mb-5">
        <p class="breadcrumbs mb-0"><span class="mr-3"><a href="index.html">Home <i class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></i></a></span> <span>Job Post</span></p>
        <h1 class="mb-3 bread">Post A Job</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SkillIndia": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/SkillIndia",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/assets/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/animate.css",
              "src/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/magnific-popup.css",
              "src/assets/css/aos.css",
              "src/assets/css/ionicons.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/ionicons.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css",
              "src/assets/css/jquery.timepicker.css",
              "src/assets/css/flaticon.css",
              "assets/css/icomoon.css",
              "assets/css/style.css" 
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SkillIndia:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "SkillIndia:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SkillIndia:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "SkillIndia:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "SkillIndia:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "SkillIndia"
}
```

Comment: Hi, take your styles and scripts to angular.json from index.html and try again

Comment: moved the styles animate.css and other css from Index.html to angular.json but it does not work

Comment: Can u create your stackblitz example please and share link which is in index.html works one

Comment: stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-67o15f

Comment: After spending so money days  i found out that ftco-animate class is  hiding the content when removed this class content start appearing but i lost animation . I am close to the solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here using https://colorlib.com/wp/template/pizza/.

But class `ftco-animate` is in styles.css (imported from template, currently stored in src/assets/css/)

```
.ftco-animate {  
    opacity: 0;  
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution please, I didn't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in `angular.json` file you have following structure:

For `assets` -

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
```

and for `styles`:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.scss",
      "src/assets/css/animate.css"
    ]
```

Include all your global styling files in styles. Adjust path accordingly.

Comment: moved the  styles animate.css from Index to angular.json but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the main.js file after the document loads. Apparently it solved my problem. Using jquery:

```
<script>
$ (document) .ready (function () {
   $ .getScript ('assets / js / main.js');
});
</script>
```

Check where you have the main.js file